# How can I run RSpec on Github Action , if it is not working?

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

[Click here to view the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzXQ2.png)     getting the error like this

```html
RSpec Tests
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - unit-testing-air
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - unit-testing-air
jobs:
  rspec:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      RAILS_ENV: test
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install postgres client
        run: sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
      - name: Install Gemfile
        run: gem install bundler -v '2.3.6'  
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: bundle install
      - name: Create database
        run: |
          bundler exec rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test
          bundler exec rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
      - name: RSpec
        run: bundler exec rspec
```

This is my .yml file included in the .github/workflows in my project. I am able to run rspec tests on my local but my sole purpose is to run the test cases as the github action on pull request or push simply .

Answer (score 1):

Here is my workflow.

Note that I deal with Postgres also which might not be your case

```yaml
name: "RSpec"
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "development" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "development" ]
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        bundler-cache: true # runs 'bundle install' and caches installed gems automatically
    - name: Set up PostgreSQL
      uses: Harmon758/postgresql-action@v1.0.0
      with:
        postgresql user: test
        postgresql password: password
    - name: Build app
      run: |
        gem install bundler
        bundle config path vendor/bundle
        bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3
        bundle exec rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test
        bundle exec rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
      env:
        DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://test:password@localhost/application_test'
    - name: Run specs
      run: |
        bundle exec rspec
      env:
        DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://test:password@localhost/application_test'
```